# database connection wont close after updating to spring 5

Tags: spring, c3p0

my project was working fine with spring 3.2 but after i udate it to spring 5 my connections to db stay open for 30 min and 1 transaction take 7 connections. i use c3p0 for database connection.
i didn't change the code and this is my config

```xml
 <bean id="pum"
          class="com.exp.jpa.integration.KaraPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations" value="${jpa.persistenceXmlLocations}"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
            <bean class="com.exp.framework.jpa.MergingPersistenceUnitPostProcessor"/>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                    class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${jpa.hibernate.dialect}"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="${jpa.schema}"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${jpa.show_sql}"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.proc.param_null_passing" value="true"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="com.exp.framework.db.KaraHibernateJpaDialect">
                <property name="name" value="Main"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
                  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="KaraPool"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jpa.dataSource.driverClass}"/>
        <property name="description" value="main pool data source"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jpa.dataSource.jdbcUrl}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${jpa.connection.user}">
        </property>
        <property name="password" value="${jpa.connection.password}">
        </property>
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>
        <property name="forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions" value="false"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${jpa.dataSource.initPoolSize:1}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jpa.dataSource.minPoolSize:1}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jpa.dataSource.maxPoolSize:10}"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${jpa.dataSource.maxIdleTime:300}"/>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true"/>
        <property name="propertyCycle" value="${jpa.dataSource.propertyCycle:60}"/>
        <!-- In Second -->
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="${jpa.dataSource.acquireRetryDelay:1000}"/>
        <!-- In Mili Second -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="${jpa.dataSource.maxConnectionAge:0}"/>
        <!-- In Second -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${jpa.dataSource.checkoutTimeout:5000}"/>
        <!-- In Mili Second -->
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jpa.dataSource.acquireIncrement:1}"/>
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="${jpa.dataSource.numHelperThreads:5}"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="${jpa.dataSource.acquireRetryAttempts:1}"/>
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout"
                  value="${jpa.dataSource.unreturnedConnectionTimeout:600}"/>
        <!-- In Second -->
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="${jpa.dataSource.breakAfterAcquireFailure:false}"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${jpa.dataSource.testConnectionOnCheckout:false}"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${jpa.dataSource.testConnectionOnCheckin:false}"/>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 0 from dual"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="mbeanServer"
          class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"/>
        <property name="registerWithFactory" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="register" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <bean factory-bean="pooledDataSourceName" factory-method="getPooledDataSourceObjectName"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="mbeanServer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledDataSourceName" class="com.exp.framework.db.PooledDataSourceBeanNameFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
        <bean name="mbeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter"
            lazy-init="false" depends-on="mbeanServer">
            <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer"></property>
            <property name="namingStrategy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.KeyNamingStrategy">
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="beans">
                <map>
                    <entry key="com.exp.pool.connection:type=c3p0,name=Main" value-ref="dataSource_c3">
                    </entry>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="assembler" >
             <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MethodExclusionMBeanInfoAssembler">
              <property name="ignoredMethods">
                <value>
                    close,
                    getConnection,
                    getLastAcquisitionFailure,
                    getLastCheckinFailure,
                    getLastCheckoutFailure,
                    getLastIdleTestFailure,
                    getLastConnectionTestFailure,
                    getConnectionPoolDataSource,
                    getNestedDataSource,
                    getReference,
                    getConnection,
                    getPassword,
                    getPooledConnection,
                    getProperties,
                    getLogWriter,
                    getLastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser,
                    getLastCheckoutFailureDefaultUser,
                    getLastCheckinFailureDefaultUser,
                    getLastIdleTestFailureDefaultUser,
                    getLastConnectionTestFailureDefaultUser,
                    setPassword,
                    setProperties,
                    setLogWriter
                    isWrapperFor
                    unwrap,
                    equals,
                    doResolve,
                    removeVetoableChangeListener,
                    addVetoableChangeListener,
                    removePropertyChangeListener,
                    addPropertyChangeListener,
                    setIdentityToken,
                    setDataSourceName,
                    getIdentityToken,
                    setConnectionPoolDataSource,
                </value>
              </property>
             </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

```java
SpringBaseEntityManagerFactoryProvider provider = new SpringBaseEntityManagerFactoryProvider(); 
EntityManagerFactory emf = provider.getEntityManagerFactory(); 
JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
jpaProperties.put("org.hibernate.flushMode", "COMMIT");
txManager.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
```

```java
DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW); 
def.setName("LogTransaction"); 
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus transactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(def); try { ... 
txManager.commit(transactionStatus);
```

i expected to use 1 connection to db for a transaction and close it after commit but after update to spring 5 it use 7 connections for 1 transaction and wont close it before 30 min

Comment: Where is your transaction manager? How did you define your transactions?

Comment: SpringBaseEntityManagerFactoryProvider provider = new SpringBaseEntityManagerFactoryProvider();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = provider.getEntityManagerFactory();
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("org.hibernate.flushMode", "COMMIT");
        txManager.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

Comment: DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        def.setName("LogTransaction");
        org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus transactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(def);
        try {
            ...
            txManager.commit(transactionStatus);

Comment: @M.Deinum this is my transaction manager

Comment: @M.Deinum the problem is the connection that opens for dmbs lock wont close before the timeout

Comment: Please don't add additional code information as comments, that is totally unreadable, edit your question instead. Why did you configure the tx manager in Java? That should be in XML as well or a Java config file. But please edit your question as the comment is unreadable.

Comment: @M.Deinum i add it to the question. i start working on this project 4 month ago i dont know why they config it in java instead of XML.

Comment: I don't get where that code is, if that is part of your regular code it is wrong to start with.